# Mysterious Wires

Tags: electrical

I found three wires in a box: 1 blue 10 AWG, 1 blue 10 AWG and one white 12 AWG.  There is a 125 volt reading across the two blue wires and a 125 volt reading across one of the blue wires and the white wire.  There is no voltage across the other blue wire and the white wire. When I shut off one 20 amp breaker the voltages disappear. Which wire is neutral and which is hot?  I thought the wires might be connected to a double breaker but not so.  Note: I am in Mexico and wire color conventions are not always adhered to.

Comment: What type of wiring method is in use here?  Are the wires together in a cable that is wrapped in a sheath/jacket?  Or do the wires run down a conduit?  (If the latter, then odd colors are normal and a good thing.)

Comment: @Harper -- this may be a bit odd even for a conduit job....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am wondering if it's a) in metal conduit, because blue-blue-white 10/10/12 Romex seems like a *highly improbable product*. And b) reused in some way from a former split-phase circuit, or maybe just one wire is broken.

Answer (score 1):

#### Looks like hot, neutral, ground

Neutral to ground should be 0V. Ground often can be legitimately smaller than hot & neutral, since it is only carrying current in fault situations.

So if my hunch is correct:

White, being the smaller wire, is ground.
The blue that is 0V blue<->white is neutral.
The other blue is hot.